# Netbeans (as RoR editor): Stop the Scanning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I've looked on the Netbeans forums, but they appear to be quite broken. I am about to give up on Netbeans my favorite Rails editor, if I cannot solve this problem.

Netbeans starts scanning projects and never stops, leaving me with no autocomplete nor any other interesting stuff. I have some very large Ruby files (40k lines: they are Excel generated code-files for DB filling), and I'd like to exclude them from scanning. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Oracle is destroying all good things that Sun had. I too use Netbeans for ROR work but Oracle is making me hate them more each day.

Comment: @MattC, I can't say that I agree, but the evidence seems to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem with netbeans , i went to forums and all & they all say it cant be done , i'm currently using text-editors , maybe i'll use radrails or rubymine

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking out RadRails now... I loved Netbeans, but they're obviously too big a company to get their sh*t together. I'm curious about what Textmate can do, since everybody talks about it so much.

Comment: Textmate is the best editor for the Mac , i'm a windows user so i'm trying to find a free textmate alternative , radrails is based on eclipse it will suit you fine , vote for my answer :)